# noexcept swap с мьютексами

Tags: c++, mutex

Считается хорошим тоном обеспечивать `noexcept-swap` функцию-член класса. Что делать, если появляется необходимость добавить в этой функции такую строчку `std::scoped_lock < std::mutex, std::mutex > lock(m_mutex, other.m_mutex);`, которая может приводить к генерации исключений?

Comment: Вроде бы noexcept означает, что функция-член не выкидывает исключений во вне. Тогда обработайте их внутри

Comment: @V-Mor Речь идет об исключениях от функций-членов lock. Все, что я могу - это проглотить их (в моем классе). Но обычно я не придеерживаюсь подобной стратегии, а стараюсь сообщать об ошибках выше

Comment: Почему только проглотить? Что мешает осуществить корректную обработку или сообщать об ошибках выше в виде кодов ошибок?

Comment: Это говорит о том, что у вашего класса не может быть никакого  noexcept swap.